# Why copying memory from VRAM to RAM is slower than RAM to VRAM? (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, gpgpu

I am creating something similar to CUDA but I saw that copy memory from RAM to VRAM is very fast like copying from RAM to itself. But copy from VRAM to RAM is a way slower than RAM to VRAM.

By the way I am using `glTexSubImage2D` to copy from RAM to VRAM and `glGetTexImage` to copy from VRAM to RAM.

Why? Is there a way to improve it's performance like copying RAM to VRAM?

Comment: @AxelGneiting GS7200 I think something with 312.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transferring data from GPU to CPU was always a very slow operation.

> [A GPU -> CPU](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/168710-Why-is-GPU-CPU-transfer-slow) readback introduces a "sync point" where the CPU must wait for the GPU to complete its calculations. During this time, the CPU stops feeding the GPU with data, causing it to stall.
>
> Now, remember that a modern GPU is designed in a highly parallel manner, with thousand threads in flight at any given moment. The sync point must wait for all those threads to finish processing, before it can readback the result of their calculations. Once the readback is complete, all those threads must restart execution from zero... bad!
>
> Reading back the results asynchronously (after a few frames), allows the GPU continue execution without its threads starving (the stop-and-resume issue outlined above). This improves performance tremendously - the more parallel the GPU, the higher the performance improvement.

Depending on your graphical chip and driver, maybe you get better performances by using [PBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html).

Comment: But RAM to VRAM is fast. (16 million floats in under 50ms but the other one is about 500ms) By the way I need textures because I use shader to modifying them

Comment: @FijiWiji Yes, it is super fast, but the other direction is super slow. I'd say 500 ms other way is fast.

Comment: @FijiWiji Well, I answered your question why it is slow. If your result is modified texture, you might get it faster by using off-screen buffers.

Comment: Thanks... But I think the other answer is too the answer. (To use BufferObject)

Answer (score 3):

> By the way I am using glTexSubImage2D to copy from RAM to VRAM and glGetTexImage to copy from VRAM to RAM.

Then you're not *copying* data. You're performing [pixel transfer operations](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer), which can require CPU modification, depending on your [image's internal format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format), the pixel transfer format, and the pixel transfer type parameters.

Since you didn't provide actual code, there's no way to know if you choose bad parameters or not.

If you want to test direct *copying* performance, use a [buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object).

Comment: Uhm, pixel transfer operations are defined as copying of memory from GPU<->CPU, it is even stated in the page you linked.